# sqlite3 add check constraint doesn't work

Tags: sqlite

I added a column to my table:

```
ALTER TABLE receivertip ADD COLUMN my_column BOOLEAN
```

then I added a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE receivertip ADD CONSTRAINT my_column_ck CHECK(my_column IN (0, 1))
```

but sqlite (I'm using **DB Browser for Sqlite**) gives me an error:

```
near "CONSTRAINT": syntax error:
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The `ALTER TABLE` command does not allow adding constraints. See the language documentation: https://sqlite.com/lang_altertable.html

To add the constraint, copy your tables contents into a new table, drop the old, then re-create the old table with the added constraint, then copy-back the data.

Comment: I don't know if it did at the time you wrote your answer, but nowadays you can add a check constraint at the same time as a column.